# Build a big MySQL high availability

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm lookign for big mysql high availability.

My idea look like

- Server
- 10 MariaDB Server

if Server 1 full disk, it will write to server 2, server 2 full write to server 3,...

And when i call record from any server, it's return match data.

So anybody have any design database, or have any keyword, please share for me.

Thanks

Sorry my bad english

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good approach to a large database. Would it not be worth considering adequate RAID arrays to host your database system on? It's also possible what you might actually require is a "Distributed Database" to maintain high avaliability and redundancy

Comment: What happens when server 10 is full?  I suggest that your plan is useless.

Comment: 10 servers with no redundancy?  If _any_ of the 10 crashes, the _entire_ system is dead.  That is not "High Availability".

Comment: Thanks all, if 10 server full, i will added new server, hardware is not trouble.

Comment: For high avaliability you need to distribute your loads and have redundancy. In addition to the "when the server is full" problem, what about all the cost overheads of running empty servers? You shouldn't treat each server as an "overflow" from the last. You seriously need to rethink your approach here, or at the very least explain your exact thought process. Having 10 servers acting as overflow for the last would be no more efficient than having 1 server with massive storage - either way (like Rick said) one crash will kill the entire system